# Equal germs at different points

Tags: sheaf-theory

Let $ X $ be a topological space. Let $ P $ be a (pre)sheaf of sets on $ X $. Let $ U\subset X $ be an open set and let $ s\in PU $ be a section of $ P $. For $ x\in X $ let $ s_x $ denote the germ of $ s $ at $ x $.

I was wondering if $ s_x = s_y $ for two points $ x,y\in U $ necessarily implies $ x = y $. I tried playing with the sheaf of continuous functions on $ \mathbb R $, but I was not able to come up with a counterexample.

Comment: You've not given any way to compare these two germs - what would it even mean for two germs to be equal?

Comment: My book defines the germ of $ s\in PU $ at $ x $ as the set of all the pairs $ (V,t) $, where $ V $ is an open nhbd of $ x $ and $ t\in PV $, such that there exists an open nhbd $ W $ of $ x $ contained in $ V\cap U $ such that $ t{\restriction_W} = s{\restriction_W} $. So $ s_x $ and $ s_y $ could be equal, at least set-theoretically.